# How should I interpret this fdisk output?

Tags: fdisk

My main hdd seems to have two partitions over the same disk space. Are `/dev/sda2 and` /dev/sda6` overlapping? How should I interpret this fdisk output? Have I screwed up my installation?

```
allan@xxxxxxxx:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sdb: 3.64 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: nal USB 3.0     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 4776929E-A713-43EF-842A-57E75E10B191

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 7814035455 7814033408  3.6T Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sda: 953.87 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk model: SPCC Solid State
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x35d82785

Device     Boot     Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048  195311615  195309568  93.1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       195313662 2000408575 1805094914 860.7G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       195313664  203124735    7811072   3.7G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       203126784 2000408575 1797281792   857G 83 Linux
```

Thank you in advance... how else could I have figured this out?

Answer (score 0):

`/dev/sda2` is an extended partition.

`/dev/sda5` and `/dev/sda6` are inside `/dev/sda2`.

If you start `gparted`, you'll see it in graphics.

Comment: THANK YOU PILOT6!